# Got "401 Unauthorized" error when deploy a maven artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, artifactory

**Update based on comment:**

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <name>Releases</name>
      <url>https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-app-libs-release</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-app-libs-snapshot/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

**Original:**

My goal is to play with an end-to-end maven repository deployment and dependency import.

I am working on deploying a maven project(project name my-app) artifact to jFrog and then add the artifact as an dependency to another maven project(project name is my-second-app)

1. I have setup the jFrog account
2. Initialized settings.xml under folder `~/.m2/` with the jFrog credentials(username and password) and specified the URL for release and snapshots
3. I have added the following plugins in project my-app:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-a-jar</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <file>
                          ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
                      </file>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>deploy</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                <url>https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-app-libs-release</url>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

4. When I run `mvn deploy`, the projects shows 401 Unauthorized error but the artifact is deployed and can be found in jFrog packages.
5. I have added the dependency in project my-second-app and the dependency can be downloaded when run `mvn install`

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

[image]

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default) on project my-app: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.mycompany.app:my-app:0.0.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany.app:my-app:0.0.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote-repository (https://myurl.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-app-libs-release): authentication failed for https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-app-libs-release/com/mycompany/app/my-app/0.0.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does anyone know what I have been missing? Why I got the 401 unauthorized error? I have added the credentials in settings.xml, my understanding is it is not required to add any credential in project level.

Comment: You usually should not need any of that business in the `maven-deploy-plugin` stanza. Instead, you should have a server defined in `distributionManagement.repository` (and matching credentials in your `.m2/settings.xml`).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Hi chrylis, I have the settings in my pom and I have past it into the question. Does that mean I don't need to specify the url in the maven-deploy-plugin chunk?

Comment: Only define distributionManagement and NOT using maven-install-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin...as you have done...

Comment: Hi chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- and khmarbaise Thanks for both of you, your suggestions are working like a charm, if you want please make the comment as an answer and i will upvote for them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven is configured with built-in defaults that work in most cases, and the standard Maven-aware repository servers like Nexus and Artifactory will work with them with minimal configuration.

Cut out the custom configuration you have for `maven-deploy-plugin` and let it use the default setup. Instead, add a `distributionManagement` section with a `repository` for your server, and make sure you have matching credentials in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the point is `id`: repository.id and server.id must be the same.

pom.xml:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>cloud-3party</id>
        <name>cloud-3party</name>
        <url>xxx</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

apaphe-maven-3.6.3/conf/setting.xml

```
<server>
  <id>cloud-3party</id>
  <username>xxx</username>
  <password>xxx</password>
</server>
```